# jquery select all inputs with class gives wrong results?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to read all inputs of class form-elementNameInput
after iterating over:

```
 <li class="liClass"><div class="containerClass">
```

There are 2 of them (text1 and text2)
For some reason I am getting wrong results from one of the buttons, I am not sure why?
I also tried

```
 $(this).first(".form-elementNameInput").text();
```

full code:

```js
function readInputText(){
  var elementText;
  $('li.liClass>div.containerClass').each(function(){     
   elementText = $(this).first("input.form-elementNameInput:text").text();
   console.log("#" + elementText + "#");
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol>
 <li class="liClass">
  <div class="containerClass">
    <input type="hidden" id="typeSave" name="typeSave" value="" />
     <div class="form-group row">
              <div class="col-xs-2">
       <input type="text" class="form-elementNameInput" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm" value="text1"></input>
       </div>
       <div class="col-xs-2">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" id="btn_sel">
             <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
             <span style="width:3em;">
              </span>Select Type
            </button>
       </div>
     </div>
  </div>
 <li>
   <li class="liClass">
  <div class="containerClass">
    <input type="hidden" id="typeSave" name="typeSave" value="" />
     <div class="form-group row">

              <div class="col-xs-2">
       <input type="text" class="form-elementNameInput" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm"  value="text2"></input>
       </div>
       <div class="col-xs-2">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" id="btn_sel">
             <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
             <span style="width:3em;">
              </span>Select Type
            </button>
       </div>
     </div>
  </div>
 <li>
</ol>

<div class="col-xs-1">
 <button class="btn btn-primary" onClick="readInputText()">read text</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason your jQuery isn't working is because you're using `.first()`, when you should be using `.find()`

[`.first()`](https://api.jquery.com/first/) will always return the first element from the set it is called from - *it does not take a parameter.*

```js
// This will select the first element from $(this) - not $('.form-elementNameInput')
$(this).first('.form-elementNameInput').text();
```

[`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) will search through the descendants of the set it is called from, and return any matching elements

```js
// This will find the .form-elementNameInput element, and then find the first()
$(this).find('.form-elementNameInput').first();
```

---

Also, you're using `.text()` to try and return the text inside your select - if the element is a  `input`, `select` or `textarea`, you should be using [`.val()`](https://api.jquery.com/val/)

```js
function readInputText() {
  $('li.liClass>div.containerClass').each(function() {
    let elementText = $(this).find("input.form-elementNameInput").first().val();
    console.log("#" + elementText + "#");
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol>
  <li class="liClass">
    <div class="containerClass">
      <input type="hidden" id="typeSave" name="typeSave" value="" />
      <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-xs-2">
          <input type="text" class="form-elementNameInput" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm" value="text1"></input>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">
          <button class="btn btn-primary" id="btn_sel">
             <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
             <span style="width:3em;">
              </span>Select Type
            </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <li>
      <li class="liClass">
        <div class="containerClass">
          <input type="hidden" id="typeSave" name="typeSave" value="" />
          <div class="form-group row">

            <div class="col-xs-2">
              <input type="text" class="form-elementNameInput" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm" value="text2"></input>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-2">
              <button class="btn btn-primary" id="btn_sel">
             <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
             <span style="width:3em;">
              </span>Select Type
            </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <li>
</ol>

<div class="col-xs-1">
  <button class="btn btn-primary" onClick="readInputText()">read text</button>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you light, its working fine ill accept it, i still don't understand why first is not working on this...    $(this).first("");

Comment: I've added a brief explanation, and an addition link to the docs

Answer (score 1):

I think you wanted to use find() instead of first()

`elementText = $(this).find("input.form-elementNameInput:text").val();`

```js
function readInputText(){
  var elementText;
  $('li.liClass>div.containerClass').each(function(){     
   elementText = $(this).find("input.form-elementNameInput:text").val();
   console.log("#" + elementText + "#");
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol>
 <li class="liClass">
  <div class="containerClass">
    <input type="hidden" id="typeSave" name="typeSave" value="" />
     <div class="form-group row">
              <div class="col-xs-2">
       <input type="text" class="form-elementNameInput" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm" value="text1"></input>
       </div>
       <div class="col-xs-2">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" id="btn_sel">
             <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
             <span style="width:3em;">
              </span>Select Type
            </button>
       </div>
     </div>
  </div>
 <li>
   <li class="liClass">
  <div class="containerClass">
    <input type="hidden" id="typeSave" name="typeSave" value="" />
     <div class="form-group row">

              <div class="col-xs-2">
       <input type="text" class="form-elementNameInput" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm"  value="text2"></input>
       </div>
       <div class="col-xs-2">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" id="btn_sel">
             <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
             <span style="width:3em;">
              </span>Select Type
            </button>
       </div>
     </div>
  </div>
 <li>
</ol>

<div class="col-xs-1">
 <button class="btn btn-primary" onClick="readInputText()">read text</button>
</div>
```